# Ranking by date in SQL but ignoring dates <3 days together

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2008-r2, rank

I would like to rank some data by date to obtain a sequential list (1, 2, 3) but ignore dates that are <3 days together.

For example:

```
11/10/2015 = 1
11/11/2015 = 2
11/12/2015 = NULL (within 3 days of previous date)
11/15/2015 = 3
```

What is an efficient way of doing this please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going for something like this. Knowing the RDBMS would help.

```
with date_lags as
    (
        select
            date,
            lag(date) over(order by date) as last_date
        from
            table
    )
select
    date,
    rank() over(order by date) as the_rank
from
    date_lags
where
    datediff(day, last_date, date) >= 3;
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit challenging, because you don't have `lag()` or cumulative sum.  But, you can implement it using `outer apply` (or a subquery):

```
select e.*,
       (case when CountFlag = 1
             then row_number() over (partition by CountFlag order by e.date)
        end) as newcol
from example e outer apply
     (select top 1 (case when e.date >= dateadd(day, 3, e2.date) then 1 else 0 end) as CountFlag
      from example e2
      where e2.date < e.date
      order by e2.date desc
     ) eprev;
```

This uses a logic trick to get the `NULL` value.  Notice there is no `WHERE`, so all values are assigned a rank.  The outer query uses the same column for the `case` condition and for the `partition by` clause.

Comment: This creates NULL in the newcolumn when two dates are the same

Comment: Replace the `<` with `<=` in the subquery.

Comment: OK thanks. How do I do this separately for each person (id) in a dataset, by partitioning? Can this be combined with partition?

Comment: @user2964644 . . . By adding something like `e2.person = e.person` in the subquery.